# Get data from column by using column name?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I iterate a DataTable's rows using -

```
DataTable dt = getDataTableFromSomeWhere();
DataRow row = null;
//for loop
row = dt.Rows[i];
```

How do I get the value of a column of the i-th row, by using the name of the column ? 
I can iterate the columns using dt.Columns[j], but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [indexer taking a string parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
object value = row["ColumnName"];
```

EDIT: Assuming the value has been fetched in an appropriate type, I'd normally just cast to the CLR type you want:

```
int someIntegerValue = (int) row["ColumnName"];
```

Sometimes you may need two levels of casting (one to unbox and then another to perform an actual value conversion) but it depends on what you need.

I would recommend *against* converting to a string representation and then parsing that, unless you've really got no alternative. Excessive string conversions not only harm performance (usually not relevant) but they lead to sloppy type choices.

Comment: Then use value.ToString() to get the value contained by the object ?

Comment: Btw, I forgot to ask, what happens if the given column name does not exist ?

Comment: @blasto: I would suggest a) checking the documentation and then b) trying it for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string name = (string) row["ColumnName"];
```

or

```
 int i = Convert.ToInt32( row["ColumnName"]);
```

referencing by name is tiny bit slower but way more readable.

Comment: Indexing by name is also much safer if you ever insert or rearrange columns.